# System cannot create OperationClient, Service client is null

Tags: websphere, apache-axis

We are trying to access a SOA service and the application is deployed in Websphere 9.0.0.3.

Once we retrieve the information from SOA service we cache the data in form of objects. Not sure if cache holding up any.

Based on the stacktrace looked up the axis2 codebase, we found that while setting up axis service, a few params will be added but those seem to be locked. I am not sure what would be the cause. Suggestions would be great.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The system cannot create the OperationClient. The ServiceClient is null.
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.createOperationClient(AxisInvocationController.java:457)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:419)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well would sound a bit lame. But what resolved my issue was a websphere server restart. It seems the last server restart did not load the Service clients and thier bindings correctly and hence my code was not able to create the operation client for a few operations.

If this does not solve the issue,you can always enable more detailed tracing by following the instructions below:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_tracewbscomp.html

Also,when you restart the servers make sure synchronization is completed between the all the nodes on the cell.